# Render Many Images in Single Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm investigating a performance issue we are having with a web form and figured I would do well to solicit some opinions here on this.

This page, on load on the server side, retrieves a list of ID values that are then used to seed a javascript block that is added at the end of the load event. The javascript then loops through these IDs and adds an `img` element for each such ID, using the ID to set the `src` attribute.

Previously, this worked fine due to a limitation of only ever showing the first 20 such images found. The business now wants to remove this limitation, which means we could reasonably see hundreds of such images and when testing this, the page takes an unacceptably long time to render all of these `img` elements.

Simplified pseudo-code for the JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
     var img = "<img src='some\path\'" + ids[i];
     //add img to document
}
```

Personally, I'd suggest we just keep the limitation in place for now as we are very late in the dev cycle for this release, but I'd like to see what, if anything, we could do to speed this up. All options are on the table, we just need all of images to be displayed. Are there alternative strategies out there to handle this sort of scenario?

Please let me know if any other details would be beneficial.
**EDIT**
I neglected to mention the reason that all of these images need to be loaded is that this page is used for printing all of these images, so paging won't really work. I agree on this not being a great design choice, but the users and/or business owners want a print-friendly page that shows all of these images. The "normal" page for this same functionality does use paging and performs admirably.
**EDIT 2**
Now that I am back at the office I can provide a little more detail:

- The img elements are using an aspx page as their src, the actual image contents are retrieved from a database in that other page and streamed back as a response using a content type of image/png, so that's a further slow down, but given the current architecture, it is necessary as we only store these images in the database
- These images can vary in size, but a couple MB for a single image would not be unusual

These responses are confirming what I thought: this is not a good idea

Comment: Try jQuery.lazyload or jQuery.scrollLoading.

Comment: javascript is fast but loading hundreds of images takes alot of time. what's the size of the iamges? filetype?

Comment: you can add simple timeout to the for loop so as to not load them all at once...

Comment: you want to load them sequentially?

Comment: In response to your update, load the images asynchronously and just show a loading message until they're all ready. Then allow them to print.

Comment: @cocco I am not at work, so I can't give truly accurate answers, but I believe the file types are always PNG and the sizes are a couple MB each. The order of them does matter in the final page, but they don't have to be loaded sequentially.

Comment: Hundreds of megabytes of images? Definitely try to persuade the business to reconsider approach. I am not sure printing won't be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a fast loading page with multiple images(hundreds) to **print**, you can't use png's at a big resolution.

First of all convert all images to jpg(keep the originals) in a size which should just big enough to print.

150dpi should be enough.

That means if you put 2 images side by side on a 20cm width paper 500pixel is enough for the max width.

so around 5-15kb per image

if you print on photopaper 1200pixels.(but that taakes longer to load 30-40kb  per image)

---

then in most browsers you can use inches or cm's to create a nice impagination.

---

if you want to print those images on one page you can use a packing script to calculate the the max size for each image.

like this

```
var best_square3=function(w,h,n){
 var s=Math.sqrt(w*h/n),c=Math.floor(w/s),r=Math.floor(h/s),t=c*r;
 while(t<=n){
  s--;
  c=Math.floor(w/s);
  r=Math.floor(h/s);
  t=c*r;
 }
 return [w,h,n,s,c,r,c*r,Math.floor(s),((100/w)*(w/c))+'%',((100/h)*(h/r))+'%'];
}
```

demo .... click somewhere inside the result box

http://jsfiddle.net/e7My4/1/

in that case your images can be much smaller. so 100px*100px max.

---

i personally use php and fpdf to create pdf's to download/print everythime i update the images/db

**EDIT**

As your using aspx (which i don't use since various years) you need to find a aspx script to resize the images before you output them in a smaller format(like i told you above) in jpg as you don't need transparency.

Comment: It probably isn't enough of a difference to make it really usable, but your answer did prompt me to play around with switching to using jpegs in the aspx page and that does have a significant impact on total time and size. I was able to get from a minute and half with 133 million bytes of PNG images for a 387 image page to one minute and 81 million bytes of JPEG images. That at least gives me something to present to the business. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do not display them all at once. Nobody could reasonably work with 100s of images at once. Use some kind of paging mechanism that would display, say, 10 images at a time.

It could be your own paging or one of the dozen jQuery image sliders/rotators/galleries.

Comment: See my update on why all of these images are loaded right away

Answer (score 2):

The rate at which images can be loaded by the browser is limited by many things, such as

- Maximum number of concurrent HTTP requests the browser will perform
- Size of the images
- Latency and connection speed loading the images
- Specific browser the user has
- Specific hardware the user has

The maximum number of concurrent HTTP requests is usually *per domain*.  Placing images on a number of different domains would help with this bottleneck.  It is also a very complex solution and I would not recommend you do that (just including the options for completeness).

You may be able to reduce the size of the images, if they are not optimally encoded.

You can reduce the latency and improve the connection speed by placing the images on a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

**At the end of the day, loading 100's of images is likely to be a poor design choice.**

Instead, consider dynamically loading additional images as the user needs them.  One example if this behavior is the infinite scroll that you see with websites such as Facebook.

**UPDATE**

As you are loading the page with the intent to print it, you can focus on the first three bullet points in my list.

You might also consider using server-side code to render all of the images into one large image.  This may be faster than opening hundreds of HTTP connections to retrieve individual images.  The down side of that approach (besides the additional complexity) is that the rendered "mega" image would not be cached by a CDN (there is no benefit in caching it.  The user requesting that combination already has it cached in the browser, and if no other geographically nearby users will likely request the same exact image mix, there is no benefit).

If you have hundreds of images that are intended to fit on a single page for print (thumbnails), make sure the images are no larger than they need to be for good print quality.  If your PNGs are a couple MB each, they are probably *way* too large for a print-quality thumbnail.